# What is the max size of string that BeanPropertyRowMapper supports?

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I have started to use Spring's BeanPropertyRowMapper more, since the majority of the time, I do not need any kind of complicated mapping.

I happen to have a table for accounts and when I changed the row mapper to the BeanPropertyRowMapper from my basic implementation, the password column would not convert over.  The passwords are saved in a varchar column of size 256.  This is an excerpt of the Account class for mapping:

Account.java

```
public class Account {
    public Account() {}

    private String email = null;
    private String password = null;
    private String firstName = null;
    private String lastName = null;

    /* Getters and Setters */
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

As for the mapper, I am just using the plain old BeanPropertyRowMapper.  This has been working for everything else so far.  The name columns are saved in varchars of size 128, and those work fine, so I am figuring the limit is somewhere in between that and 256.

I have went ahead and checked to see if it is returning from the database, and it does seem that way.  When I subclass the bean row mapper, I see that the ResultSet has the password column, and when I check the bean properties using Inspector, it sees the password property there as well.

I currently have it hard coded to insert the data into the object in the subclass I created, but it would be nice to know if this is something that would be easy to fix.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking, but 255 is a monster password.

Comment: Are you saying you think `BeanPropertyRowMapper` is truncating String values somehow? That would be really weird and IMO a bug.

Comment: @Tunaki Not that it is truncating it, just that it refuses to accept it.  It appeared as if it skipped over the column completely.

Comment: @EJP I am curious if the issue is with how I have implemented the Bean, which I don't think is the case, or if the mapper just doesn't support values that large.